# Remaining space on cloudera hadoop cluster in human readable format

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I am looking for a command that shows the human readable form of the space left on hadoop cluster. I found a command on this forum and the output is in the image.

hdfs dfsadmin -report

[output of dfsadmin command][1]

I heard that there is another command in hortonworks that gives a more human readable output. And that command is hdfs dfsadmin -report

That command doesn't seem to work on cloudera. 
Is there any equivalent command in cloudera? 
Thanks much

Comment: Your image link isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't matter whether you're using Cloudera or Hortonworks. If you're using an older version of hadoop the command might be `hadoop dfsadmin -report`.

Other options you have are:

**hadoop fs -df -h**

```
$ hadoop fs -df -h
Filesystem          Size     Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://<IP>:8020  21.8 T  244.2 G     21.6 T    1%
```

Shows the capacity, free and used space of the filesystem. If the filesystem has
  multiple partitions, and no path to a particular partition is specified, then
  the status of the root partitions will be shown.

**hadoop fs -du -h /**

```
$ hadoop fs -du -h /
772      /home
437.3 M  /mnt
0        /tmp
229.2 G  /user
9.3 G    /var
```

Shows the amount of space, in bytes, used by the files that match the specified file pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.